# Finding the size of a file

Tags: c, memory-management, file

I recently learned that sometimes, when running code, the compiler(or whatever it is) ignores when there isn't enough memory for say, a string, and interacts with the string normally.

Yes, I know this is a "lucky" thing that shouldn't happen, but sometimes does.

I often find trouble when I'm trying to interact with the contents of file, as I often run out of allocated memory and I have trouble dynamically re-allocating.

To fix this, I created two functions:

- fsizeof_full <- returns the full size of the file(as if it were a string)
- fsizeof_buffer <- returns the size of the largest line in the file

So far, as I have been using these, I have not come across any problems involving segmentation faults, but I am not sure if I am just getting lucky.

Here is my code(these both have `stdio.h` included):

#### fsizeof_full

```
unsigned int fsizeof_full(FILE *fp) {
    unsigned int size;
    while(getc(fp) != EOF)
        ++size;
    return size;
}
```

#### fsizeof_buffer

```
int fsizeof_buffer(FILE *fp) {
    int buff = 0; // holds the largest size of a line
    int temp = 0; // holds the size of the current line

    int c;
    while((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        ++temp;
        if(c == '\n') {
            buff = (temp > buff)?(temp):(buff);
            temp = 0;
        }
    }
    return buff;
```

Along with the above question("So far, as I have..."), could you possibly include more thoughts about the code regarding efficiency, necessity, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `fseek` and `ftell` to calculate the file size for you without having to read every character:

```
long fsize(FILE *fp) {
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long bytes = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    return bytes;
}
```

Note that you should open the file in binary mode in order to compute this with `fseek`. Further, note that this is portable, as all of these functions are part of standard C (`stdio.h` specifically), while `fstat` requires a POSIX-based system.

All this having been said, it's not really necessary. When reading a file, you should define a buffer of a specific size, and use a function like `fgets`, which takes a maximum number of characters to read. For example:

```
FILE* fp;
// Open file, checking for errors, etc.
char buffer[4096];
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: fstat has a windows equivalent called _fstat

Comment: Suggest 1) delete `rewind(fp);` out as going back to the beginning is not necessarily where `fp` was when the function started or 2) perform an `ftell()` up front and restore the position.

Comment: I'm really surprised( read: disappointed ) to find advice suggesting fseek() and SEEK_END on code review. [Do not use fseek() and ftell() to compute the size of a regular file](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/FIO19-C.%20Do%20not%20use%20fseek%28%29%20and%20ftell%28%29%20to%20compute%20the%20size%20of%20a%20regular%20file)

Comment: This is plain undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

For the first function you can address the OS to find out for you:

```
unsigned long long fsizeof_full(FILE *fp) {
    struct stat size;
    fstat(fileno(fp), &size);
    return size.st_size;
}
```

You'll need to include the following headers for it to work.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
```

Or you can simply seek to the end of the file (with `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END)`) and use `ftell`

Besides that files nowadays can easily exceed 4 gigabytes which will overflow the int, both posix and windows have (differently named) variants on ftell that returns a 64 bit number.

Comment: Does not `st_size` use type `off_t`, some  signed integer, not necessarily `int`?

Comment: The `fseek()`/`ftell()` method invokes undefined behavior for a binary stream. See: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FIO19-C.%20Do%20not%20use%20fseek()%20and%20ftell()%20to%20compute%20the%20size%20of%20a%20regular%20file

Answer (score 2):

1. `fsizeof_full()` code fails as it does not initialize `size`.
2. The size of a file and the range of `unsigned` are unrelated.   Assume file sizes could be much larger.

   ```
   // unsigned int fsizeof_full(FILE *fp) {
   unsigned long long fsizeof_full(FILE *fp) {
     // unsigned int size;
     unsigned long long size = 0;
     while(getc(fp) != EOF)
       ++size;
     return size;
   }
   ```
3. `fsizeof_buffer()`: Use meaningful variable names.
4. Since the value returned is likely for an array, use `size_t`.
5. `fsizeof_buffer()` has incorrect functionality.   If the file consisted of only "1234567890", the function would return 0 rather than 10.  Code needs to consider that the last line might not end in `'\n'`.

   ```
   size_t fsizeof_buffer(FILE *fp) {
     size_t largest_line = 0;
     size_t current_line = 0;

     while((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
       current_line++;
       if (c == '\n') {
         largest_line = (current_line > largest_line) ? current_line : largest_line;
         current_line = 0;
       }
     }
     largest_line = (current_line > largest_line) ? current_line : largest_line;
     return largest_line;
   }
   ```